# how to publish angular app using filezila in wwwroot folder in azure websites

Tags: angular, ftp, azure-web-app-service

i have build the angular application and i need to publish it in azure websites. I have file zilla and azure websites web app service. I have file zilla ftp. in the azure website I'm having a folder structure

```
/site/wwwroot
```

I have done the ng build -prod and generated dist. folder. what are the folders i need to copy and paste in the remote site inside the wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use File zilla. Create a .zip file of your dist folder. Drag and drop on a website and you're done.

Lets say your website is

https://my-website.azurewebsites.net

Go to https://my-website.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI

All Azure App websites have this scm subdomain with a ZipDeployUI path. Drag and drop the .zip file from your desktop to this page. It will unzip the file for you and list all the files. You can then check our your https://my-website.azurewebsites.net and see your changes.

For instance, this is mine.

[image]